# PHP. Cессия через раз сохраняет значение

Tags: php, php7, php.ini

Есть некое значение, которую я должен сохранять в сессию. Проблема в том, что сохраняется она через раз, и при следующих запросах её нет. При этом, в первом запросе, после того как значение сохраняется в $_SESSION, её там видно, но в следующих уже нет. Там либо остается либо то значение, которую сессия всё таки сохранила когда то (то есть старое), либо null, если впервые заходишь на сайт. Сессия включена, статус проверял. В куках PHPSESSID отсылаются, session_id() выдает то же значение, что и в куках шлётся. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Метод $this->key($key) выдает тот же $key, но с добавлением префикса в каком приложении сейчас запущен скрипт. Ключ всегда одинаковый, я проверял.

Я сделал маленький скрипт в той же части программы где были проблемы с сессиями. И вот снова подобная же странность. Впервый раз он сохранял нормально, $counter увеличивался, но стоило перезапустить браузер, так он снова перестал сохранять и постоянно выводить "null 0". Через какое то время он снова начинает работать правильно.

```php
    public function test()
    {
        $session = engine\registry::get(engine\session::class);

        $counter = $session->get('test');

        var_dump($counter);

        if ($counter === null) {
            $counter = 0;
        } else {
            $counter++;
        }

        $session->set('test', $counter);
        var_dump($session->get('test'));
    }
```

Comment: Было бы хорошо, если бы вы привели код. Которым вы пишите значение в сессию и потом читаете.
А вообще желательно проверить что в настройках PHP корректно настроен путь для сохранения файлов сессии и указанная папка доступна для записи со стороны вебсервера.

Comment: Я добавил скриншоты с кодом. Просто я думаю, что проблема не в коде, так как я проверял массив $_SESSION после того, как сетил туда значение и оно там было. Сессия при этом включена была, так как session_status() выдавал 2, что значит, что он активен.

Comment: при запросах ид сессии то остается постоянным?

Comment: Код картинками - это не очень хорошая практика. Картинка пропадет с сервиса скриншотов и вопрос уже будет непонятным. И для диагностиики проблемы лучше написать простой скрипт. Вроде того что их переменной сесии берется значение и выводится. Значение увеличивается на 1 и записывается в сессию. При обновлении такой страницы счетчик должен увеличиваться. Если не увеличивается - значит проблема в настройках. Если увеличивается - значит проблема где-то в вашем коде.

Comment: @teran, я дополнил вопрос

Comment: а нет, немного ступил, что не отправлял PHPSESSID на тестовом скрипте. Он работает всегда нормально.

Comment: @newman в вопросе сделал как вы просили